# How to query to see if a set of numbers have been duplicated before in SQL Server on the same table?

Tags: sql-server

Due to the huge Powerball $2.3 billion jackpot, I was wondering how does one query a lottery database where there are columns num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6 for a certain draw date and compare that to past winning numbers on itself to see if there are duplicate sets? (ie. if the winning numbers have ever repeated itself)?

Couldn't think of how to query - I am a newbie in SQL

Comment: Don't buy into the "Hot Hand Fallacy" or that there are patterns or even overdue numbers.   Each drawing is independent of the prior and each ball as well.   I'd suggest if we could forecast lotterys ... Wall Street would be empty.

Comment: This is true, if the winning numbers were 123456 this week, the chance of the exact same 123456 being drawn next week is still exactly equal to any other combination.

Comment: I was just curious to see if it has ever duplicated and the answer is NO as of Nov 7's draw and some lucky SOB in Altadena CA won it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the schema was as described, you could simply `GROUP BY` all six columns to see if the numbers had repeated. This would work for the jackpot, smaller prizes would require additional work.

```
SELECT num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, COUNT(*) AS Frequency
FROM LotteryTable
GROUP BY num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: The order of selected numbers is irrelevant though, 1,2,3,4,5,6 is the same winning numbers as 6,5,4,3,2,1

Comment: That's correct, every published lottery number I've ever seen is published in ascending order though. I've assumed they would be in the database the same way. If that's not correct, this wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, the database is ordered in ascending so the solution works!  But let's say if it didn't, then I guess one would have arrange each row in ascending and then compare?